# Undefined variable: mysqli & call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm kinda new to mysqli and I'm trying to display data on a table.

Here's the code:

```
<tbody>
   <?php
   $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT username,password,FName,LName,userAddress FROM tbl_users");
   $no = 1;
   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
   ?>
   <tr>
  <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['password'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['FName'] .' '. $row['LName'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['userAddress'] ?></td>
  <td>
      <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['userid'] ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
     <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete data')" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['userid'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</tbody>
```

These are the errors:

> Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\company\admin\user_table.php on line 205
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\company\admin\user_table.php on line 205

Comment: pass db connection in query : $mysqli->query($conn, "SELECT username,password,FName,LName,userAddress FROM tbl_users");

Comment: @Krishna, no, $mysqli would be the connection resource, it's either the oop-style where the object _is_ the connection resource _or_ the procedual style where you pass the resource as a parameter.

Comment: If you haven't created a connection to your database, you need to do so. If you have, are you sure you named it `$mysqli` ?

Comment: Off topic, but this jumped out at me from your code: You should never have any reason to echo a user's password. If you're doing things properly, the passwords will hashed and unreadable anyway so no point outputting them.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined variable: mysqli  means you didn't create object 'mysqli' or not able to get object `mysqli`; i.e. you will have to [establish a connection](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) to the MySQL server by [creating an instance](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) of mysqli *before* you can use this instance to send queries to the server.

> create object

```
$mysqli = new Mysqli("host","db user","db password","db name");
```

//conect with database

> For how to check whether the connection was established successfully, 
>   see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php .

Comment: For how to check whether the connection was established successfully, see http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.connections . And an explaination why and how this is relevant to the question would be nice, too ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK you can vote up if my code is solve issue of  Undefined variable: mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Epodax for reminding that. Just changed my config to $mysqli.

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','sa','company');
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
echo "Connection Failed".$mysqli->connect_error;
}
?>
```

Comment: You might want to add a bit more error handling. The remaining script can't "live" without the working connection, so, only printing the error message won't suffice (and [might be dangerous](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_Leakage)). You should print a "sorry, unavailable" page _instead_ of the users table in case something went wrong with the mysql connection. And `$mysqli->query` may also fail; you should add error handling there, too. `if ( !$query ) { ....error handler ... } else { while( $row = ...`